# CSS Grid row max height 1fr, scroll content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a 'calendar' layout using the following css-grid styles:

```
.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1.5em 1.5em repeat(6, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

(Codepen https://codepen.io/joelhoward0/pen/vJLmWK)

The first two rows are a 'controls' header and days of the week headers, followed by divs for each day in the month:

```
<div class="day">
  <div class="header">26</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Each day has a `.header` and `.content` div. I want the `.header` div to take up 1/5 of the height of the row, and the content to take up 4/5 and scroll if the content overflows.

However, any combination of styles I've tried just leads to `.content` growing, shrinking the other grid rows to compensate. I assume this is due to the use of `1fr` on the container grid-template-rows.

Is it possible to achieve a max height of 4/5 of the grid row height, which is 1/6 of the vertical space available, on the `.content` div?

(**Note:** setting `overflow-y: auto;` on `.day` achieves what I want, but the header is included in the scrolling area. Setting `overflow-y: auto;` on `.content` doesn't seem to do anything.)

Answer (score 16):

Although @MichaelB's response is technically correct, I have found that you **can** actually do it without resorting to specifying heights manually. And it's dead simple to do it too.

In addition to adding `overflow:auto` to the grid-item you want scrollbars on, you also need to add an `overflow:auto` to the **parent** of that grid-item.

https://codepen.io/kumarharsh/pen/jejGMm?editors=1100

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1.5em 1.5em repeat(6, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.dayHeader {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.day {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  overflow: auto; /* added overflow here! */
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.controls {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 8;
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="controls">July 2017</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Sunday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Monday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Thursday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Friday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Saturday</div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">25</div>
    <div class="content">
      this is a lot of content that I want to have scroll instead of just stretching the grid row and forcing the other rows to be smaller to compensate for this one's increased size due
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">26</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">27</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">28</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">29</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">30</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">2</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">3</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">4</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">5</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">6</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">7</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">8</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">9</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">10</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">11</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">12</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">13</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">14</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">15</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">16</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">17</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">18</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">19</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">20</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">21</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">22</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">23</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">24</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">25</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">26</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">27</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">28</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">29</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">30</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">31</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">2</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">3</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">4</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">5</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best of all, It works in all browsers (tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge), so it's likely not a hack, but an intended behaviour.

### Why does this happen?

I can't find a clear answer in the spec **yet**, but I'll keep looking and update here when I have something concrete.

### Update

Do read @Victoria's followup comment: [CSS Grid row max height 1fr, scroll content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395184/css-grid-row-max-height-1fr-scroll-content/53079691?noredirect=1#comment102995214_53079691) which has another way to do it - I'd recommend you use that way if your design allows it.

Comment: Searching further, an alternative to placing auto on the parent is to size the grid track with  " minmax( 0, 1fr ) " instead of plain  " 1fr ".  See https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1777

Comment: @Victoria you are correct - I learnt this too a few months back. I'll update my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you ever found an answer in the spec? I came across a similar behavior while using the flex layout and couldn't pinpoint the reason why

Answer (score 11):

Each row in the grid (except for the headers) is set to `1fr` height. That means each row will consume an equal proportion of free space in the container.

Just note that `fr` sizing doesn't actually define a length – either `width` or `height`. With `fr` you are simply distributing free space.

But for the `overflow` property to work, an actual height must be defined:

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.
>
> *<sup>source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow</sup>*

Therefore, consider using actual heights as opposed to space distribution. Here's an example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1.5em 1.5em repeat(6, 175px);  /* adjusment */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.dayHeader {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.day {
  height: 175px;  /* new */
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.header { /* new */
  height: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 80%; /* new */
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.controls {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 8;
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="controls">July 2017</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Sunday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Monday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Thursday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Friday</div>
  <div class="dayHeader">Saturday</div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">25</div>
    <div class="content">
      this is a lot of content that I want to have scroll instead of just stretching the grid row and forcing the other rows to be smaller to compensate for this one's increased size due
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">26</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">27</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">28</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">29</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">30</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">2</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">3</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">4</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">5</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">6</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">7</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">8</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">9</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">10</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">11</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">12</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">13</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">14</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">15</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">16</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">17</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">18</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">19</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">20</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">21</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">22</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">23</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">24</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">25</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">26</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">27</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">28</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">29</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">30</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">31</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">2</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">3</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">4</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <div class="header">5</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxwQLa)

Comment: This definitely works, but I was hoping for a solution that didn't require fixed heights on the rows. I wanted them to take up 1/6 of the available space, but prevent growth beyond that. Seems like the grid rules don't allow for that?

Comment: It's not the grid rules. It's the `overflow` property that requires a fixed length to actually overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you set the header to `position: fixed`, set `calc(100%/7)` and give it a non-transparent `background`. Set `.day` to `overflow-y:auto` and give your `.content` a `margin-top` that seems to work as well as keeping the calender fluid to the browser height.

If it's important for the header to be the full width of the day block with borders you can add your current border properties to only the right side and add `box-sizing: border-box`

```
.header{
  position:fixed;
  background: white;
  width: calc(100%/7);
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.day {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/PKZmXO)