# Cannot fill available viewport and make columns to overflow within grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an element with grid display which has 3 columns - `SectionOne`, `SectionTwo`, `SectionThree`. Column in the middle is also a grid which contains 3 rows - `SectionTwoTop`, `SectionTwoCenter`, `SectionTwoBottom`. I want:

1. `.content` to take up only space available in the viewport (so it wouldn't cause the page to overflow).
2. Elements `SectionOne`, `SectionTwoCenter`, and `SectionThree` to overflow if content within them does not fit into a viewport.
3. `.footer` to be visible at the bottom.

Now, the problem is not so much the `.content` itself but the current layout where I want to add these changes. I just cannot achieve the result that I want within that layout. Anyway, I would prefer only to make changes to `.content` and its child elements and not to the surrounding layout.

Here is a relevant code:

`index.css`

```
.container-blueprint {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "SectionOne SectionTwo SectionThree"
    "SectionOne SectionTwo SectionThree"
    "SectionOne SectionTwo SectionThree";
}

.SectionOne {
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SectionOne;
  width: 300px;
}

.SectionTwo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "SectionTwoTop SectionTwoTop SectionTwoTop"
    "SectionTwoCenter SectionTwoCenter SectionTwoCenter"
    "SectionTwoBottom SectionTwoBottom SectionTwoBottom";
  grid-area: SectionTwo;
}

.SectionThree {
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SectionThree;
  width: 100px;
}

.SectionTwoTop {
  height: 100px;
  grid-area: SectionTwoTop;
}

.SectionTwoCenter {
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SectionTwoCenter;
}

.SectionTwoBottom {
  height: 100px;
  grid-area: SectionTwoBottom;
}

/* Other styles. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr min-content;
}

.container-blueprint * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  grid-area: 1/1/2/3;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: 2/2/3/3;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: 2/1/4/2;
}

.content {
  grid-area: 3/2/4/3;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: 4/1/5/3;
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">[HEADER]</div>
    <div class="nav">[NAV]</div>
    <div class="sidebar">[SIDEBAR]</div>

    <!-- BEGIN  -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-blueprint">
        <div class="SectionOne">[SECTION ONE]</div>
        <div class="SectionTwo">
          <div class="SectionTwoTop">[SECTION TWO TOP]</div>
          <div class="SectionTwoCenter">[SECTION TWO CENTER]</div>
          <div class="SectionTwoBottom">[SECTION TWO BOTTOM]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="SectionThree">[SECTION THREE]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END -->

    <div class="footer">[FOOTER]</div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to an interactive demo:

[image: Edit admiring-rgb-945x63]

I can achieve what I want by using `calc(100vh - <height of the top content>)` on the relevant elements but I do not want to use this approach because I may not know height of the elements and it feels like a bad approach overall (for example, after height in top elements changes, I need to update `calc()` function again to prevent page overflow or gap below). I tried various approaches with `flex` and `table` display options but I cannot for the life of me get the result that I want.

Comment: Possible guidance:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45395184/3597276

Comment: Possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43311943/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it. I only needed to add these rules:

```
.content {
    min-height: 0;
}

.container-blueprint {
    height: 100%;
}
```